# Posting data from notes documents with java agent to PHP file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

With Ibm notes I got a Java Agent which posts fields from 50.000 notes documents to a website which has a PHP file. It does a single post per document. Eventually this PHP file does some job on that documents.

After a few thousand documents my Notes crashes. In the log file I can't find anything. Can't Notes handle this?

Comment: Code sample? Which line of the code is the agent crashing at? ... Are you running the code from your notes client? You should use the Java Debug Console for for more details. From what you describe here this can have a million reasons, Ia very likely reason is that you run into a OutOfMemory exception due to (lack of?) garbage collection...

Comment: Problem is I can't use java debugger on the notes server if we start http task then the server get locks or semaphores problems.. in notes server log file i see no errors.. I run the agent from my client but it takes data from notes server.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem if you explicitly coded the agent to access data on the server. I.e., include the server name in any calls to open databases instead of "" for local.

Comment: I don't think the problem is Notes client. We run some java code that dumps 100.000 lines in a Excel spreadsheet flawlessly.

Please, post your code.

Comment: had to do with the recycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing at least one required call to the `recycle()` method of some of the objects you're using. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097861).

And also consider switching to use the [OpenNTF Domino API](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/summary) instead. (Actually, I think the [github home](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino) for it is better for you to check out than the OpenNTF site.) One of the improvements it makes over the standard API from IBM is that it [handles the recycling](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/On-Recycling) for you, so you won't have problems with running out of that pesky back-end storage allocated by the Notes C API underneath the Java layer.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but how do I install / use this new API and will it have effect on my old code?

Comment: There's info on this set of slides. https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/OliverBusse/utilizing-the-openntf-domino-api

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make easier Lotus Notes development with Java, I started an Open Source project some years ago, http://riverframework.org.

It supports the native IBM Java libraries and OpenNTF Domino API. The framework handles the recycling too. Because of time, I couldn't keep working on it, but the last version was stable. I used it in real projects.

HTH,